# How to add value in parent from each child array of object field in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate

I cannot add the fields on each element in an array

I use mongodb 3.6, let say that I have a this documents in mongodb

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("648fc2857edfa7ee4f1ce31c"),
    "userId": "1",
    "groups": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("648fc2857edfa7ee4f1ce31d"),
        "groupId": "1",
        "groupLeads": [
          {
            "userId": "4"
          },
          {
            "userId": "5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("648fc2857edfa7ee4f1ce31d"),
        "groupId": "2",
        "groupLeads": [
          {
            "userId": "2"
          },
          {
            "userId": "3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to add a field under the `groups` array lets called `gLead`
so I use the aggregate function to do that like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "groups.gLead": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$groups",
          "as": "g",
          "in": "$$g.groupLeads.userId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

why the query return like this on first array

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("648fc2857edfa7ee4f1ce31d"),
  "gLead": [
    [
      "4",
      "5"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "3"
    ]
  ],
  "groupId": "1",
  "groupLeads": [
    {
      "userId": "4"
    },
    {
      "userId": "5"
    }
  ]
},
```

instead of

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("648fc2857edfa7ee4f1ce31d"),
  "gLead": [ "4", "5" ],
  "groupId": "1",
  "groupLeads": [
    {
      "userId": "4"
    },
    {
      "userId": "5"
    }
  ]
},
```

what query of aggregate should I use?

mongodb playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xokkBwgRR2s

Comment: From your query, I don't see there is possible that it will return the document with `gLead` field, but the `gLead` field will be within the `groups` array. While MongoDB version 3.6 is quite old, would propose upgrading MongoDB to at least version 4.4.

Comment: I found the answer below and it compatible with MongoDB v3.6 and thank you for your suggestion. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a pipeline that `$mergeObject`s the `$map`ped information together? Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      groups: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$groups",
          "as": "g",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$g",
              {
                gLead: "$$g.groupLeads.userId"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TQ4wVDeOcZ2)

*This answer originally used `$zip` but the output format wasn't quite right*

Comment: Yes that is true what I looking for. I barely know that map, reduce and merge objects function within array has different result as I know in javascript. Thank you